# while loop printing list in python

Tags: python, loops

The following code:

```
c=0 while c < len(demolist):
    print ’demolist[’,c,’]=’,demolist[c] 
    c=c+1
```

Creates this output:

```
demolist[ 0 ]= life
demolist[ 1 ]= 42
demolist[ 2 ]= the universe
demolist[ 3 ]= 6
demolist[ 4 ]= and
demolist[ 5 ]= 7
demolist[ 6 ]= everything
```

What's up with the `demolist[',c,']` format that is being printed in the while loop? Why does this give a number in the brackets, whereas putting `demolist[c]` there just prints that exactly?

Comment: I see no reason for this question to have been -1d. +1d to compensate.

Answer (score 5):

The print statement receives four arguments (separated by commas):

```
’demolist[’   # string
c             # integer
’]=’          # string
demolist[c]   # result of list access
```

A clearer way to write that line is:

```
print 'demolist[ {0} ]= {1}'.format(c, demolist[c])
```

See it working on line: [ideone](http://ideone.com/INcLm)

---

Note: You may also want to consider using [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) here instead of a while loop.

```
for n, elem in enumerate(demolist):
    print 'demolist[ {0} ]= {1}'.format(n, elem)
```

See it working on line: [ideone](http://ideone.com/mcWb7)

Answer (score 2):

`print ’demolist[’,c,’]=’,demolist[c]` prints the string `"demolist["`, the value of `c`, the string `"]="`, and the value of `demolist[c]`, separated by spaces.

Answer (score 1):

`c` is an integer. `demolist[c]` returns the value at index `c` from the list, `demolist`.

`print ’demolist[’,c,’]=’` prints the series of objects, with an implicit conversion to a string (which is why you don't need to explicitly convert c (an integer) to a string).

A better way of writing this code is

```
for idx, item in enumerate(demolist):
    print 'demolist[%d] = %s' % (idx, item)
```